# cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (155, 255, 0), 2) throwing error TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to draw a rectangle on an image using following code

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (155, 255, 0), 2)
```

I have used the same code in past and it worked very well. I don't know why is it not working now. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? A minimal working example of your code would helpful and the full traceback. This [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15465) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I read following threads

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15465

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16432

It appears that `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, `endY` must be integers. In my case they were fractions bewteen `0` and `1`. I multiplied `startX`, `endX` with image width and `startY`, `endY` with image height and converted them to int.

```
(startX, startY, endX, endY) = rect
startX = int(startX * W)
startY = int(startY * H)
endX = int(endX * W)
endY = int(endY * H)

cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (155, 255, 0), 2)
```

This solved the issue for me.